# Clean way to write code for nullable boolean

Tags: c#, asp.net, nullable

Is there a cleaner way to write this code.  I get the feeling there may be, but I don't know how.

```
    if (loadedFormData.Education.AwardedADegree==true)
    {
        this.radiobuttonNoAwarded.Checked = false;
        this.radiobuttonYesAwarded.Checked = true;
    }
    if (loadedFormData.Education.AwardedADegree == false)
    {
        this.radiobuttonNoAwarded.Checked = true;
        this.radiobuttonYesAwarded.Checked = false;
    }
    else // AwardedADegree is null
    {
        this.radiobuttonNoAwarded.Checked = false;
        this.radiobuttonYesAwarded.Checked = false;

    }
```

Comment: This should probably be posted on code review, not SO.

Comment: You need to clarify that it's nullable.

Comment: Its worth noting that in your original logic there is a bug due to the fact your second if is not an elseif. If `AwardedADegree` is true then it will run the first block as expected but will then also run the else block. I'm assuming this is a bug rather than by design. :)

Comment: thanks I didn't notice that

Comment: It is also possible to say `switch (loadedFormData.Education.AwardedADegree) { case true: /* ... */` and so on.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ask the question "when should my `radiobutton` be checked", instead of "what should happen when my data is true/false/null".

```
this.radiobuttonNoAwarded.Checked = loadedFormData.Education.AwardedADegree == false;
this.radiobuttonYesAwarded.Checked =  loadedFormData.Education.AwardedADegree == true;
```

Comment: I like this answer. Upvoted. But since many developers don't expect lifted operators (in this case the lifted `==`), I personally tend to write `loadedFormData.Education.AwardedADegree == (bool?)false`. That makes code like this a lot easier to understand for people who may not immediately realize that `AwardedADegree` is nullable.

Answer (score 5):

I'll assume `bool?` to allow the value to be null.

```
this.radiobuttonNoAwarded.Checked = AwardedADegree.HasValue && AwardedADegree.Value;
this.radiobuttonYesAwarded.Checked = AwardedADegree.HasValue && !AwardedADegree.Value;
```

Comment: Rotem's answer is actually correct.  `operator ==` is lifted to be able to compare a `bool` and a `bool?` and return the proper results.  (and do it in less code than here)

Comment: @Erik I didn't understand how the nullable bool nullifies my answer (pun intended)

Comment: @Rotem or my lack of understanding `bool?`with the == operator!  Although I would still write it like this as it's a little more verbose.

Comment: @ErikPhilips I agree, seeing `HasValue` instantly lets you know you're looking at a `bool?`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
 this.radiobuttonNoAwarded.Checked = (!loadedFormData.Education.AwardedADegree) ?? false;
 this.radiobuttonYesAwarded.Checked = loadedFormData.Education.AwardedADegree ?? false;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
this.radiobuttonNoAwarded.Checked = (loadedFormData.Education.AwardedADegree ?? false);
this.radiobuttonYesAwarded.Checked = !(loadedFormData.Education.AwardedADegree ?? true);
```

Comment: @Nicolas Voron - Sorry, we must've been typing our answers at the same time. :=)

Comment: No problem. But your answer isn't correct. `radiobuttonNoAwarded` must be the negation of `AwardedADegree`. In your solution, it isn't. (EDIT : and your second line isn't correct either ;) )